# What tags do we want to feed from M&TV?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-feed, movies.se

We have a feed from *[Movies & Television](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)* into our main chat room, *[The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)*.

Since the URL for the feed is limited in length, which tags from M&TV are we interested in?

Do we just want to [sort their tags by popularity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) and start at the top, adding relevant tags to our feed until we reach the maximum length?

Or do we want to make sure that all the classics are there? Or do we perhaps want to leave room for new, temporarily hot tags? Or perhaps even use a separate feed for those?

Comment: [story-identification]... Oh, wait...

Answer (score 4):

I propose 3 feeds into the room from M&TV a main feed, ID feed and current feed:

### Main feed

The main feed will bring in the general stuff we are interested in:

- the-hobbit
- x-men-cinematic-universe
- the-lord-of-the-rings
- star-wars
- doctor-who
- star-trek
- dceu
- dcau
- arrowverse
- harry-potter
- fantastic-beasts
- mcu
- game-of-thrones
- *spider-man*

*Interstellar* is also currently on the feed but I don't think we need it. There are also tags like:

- the-walking-dead
- pirates-of-the-caribbean
- terminator-series

which might be useful to add.

### ID feed

Although ID questions are now off topic on M&TV they still occasionally get some and some of these are SFF-nal in nature. Therefore, it is probably worthwhile having a feed to try and pick these up so we can identify them easier to "bring over". This would be for:

- science-fiction
- fantasy

The [identify-this-*] tags are blacklisted per my understanding so we don't need those.

### Current feed

This would be for "current" hot SFF-nal films if M&TV has a dedicated tag for those and would be updated "regularly". Currently it should have things such as the following on it (+more but these are all that came to me initially):

- avengers-infinity-war
- deadpool-2
- ant-man-and-the-wasp
- the-crimes-of-grindelwald

This feed should not have works in it that are covered by the main feed so the above are probably ruled out. We don't need clutter.

Comment: Great idea, but don't knock _Interstellar_ — it has more questions than _The Hobbit_, _The Lord of the Rings_, or _Doctor Who_, for instance. Maybe I should watch it.

Comment: @SQB A lot of questions but not recently, only a handful this year.

Comment: @SQB Like any other standalone film (especially one without *any* ties to some kind of overarching franchise structure) that is a very seasonal tag (with the season being...over, so to say). But...yes, you should definitely watch the film anyway. ;-)

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have the Current Feed cover tags that are already covered by the broader tags in the Main Feed (which is the case for all your listed examples). On the contrary, if those are different feeds, it will actually add tremendous clutter by feed repetion.

Comment: @TARS Fair point, I meant for the current feed to be current works that will get updated regularly, they're just what popped into my head. If the work is covered by a franchise tag though not much point adding it again... will clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure including the "science-fiction" and "fantasy" tags will help catch ID questions. In my experience, ever since the tag was blacklisted, people just tag them with anything that might be tangentially related to their question.

Comment: @F1Krazy Admitedly my experience is quite narrow but I’ve only seen them on Id Qs so far.